# how can I fix this, "Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , dv) : undefined columns selected"

Tags: r

This data set is from an experiment that I carried out via open sesame. The results were put into excel and then processed using r. The experiment investigates the impact of task difficulty on mind wandering tense.

The code is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(BayesFactor)

data$subject_nr <- factor(data$subject_nr)
data$Condition <- factor(data$Condition)
data$wandering.easy <- factor(data$easy_past_wandering, data$easy_future_wandering, data$easy_no_wandering)
data$wandering.hard <- factor(data$hard_past_wandering, data$hard_future_wandering, data$hard_no_wandering)

bf <- anovaBF(formula = rt ~ Condition*wandering.easy + subject_nr, data = data.frame(data), whichRandom = "subject_nr")
```

Here is the sample data:

```
structure(list(subject_nr = structure(c(2L, 14L, 8L, 7L, 9L), .Label = c("18728", 
"18783", "18799", "18853", "18859", "18886", "18891", "18897", 
"18899", "18907", "18919", "18922", "19325", "19531", "19641", 
"19815", "19862"), class = "factor"), easy_past_wandering = c(1L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L), easy_future_wandering = c(1L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L
), easy_no_wandering = c(6L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 8L), hard_past_wandering = c(1L, 
4L, 2L, 0L, 0L), hard_future_wandering = c(0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L
), hard_no_wandering = c(8L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 9L), Condition = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("control", "experimental"), class = "factor"), 
    wandering = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("6", 
    "4", "3", "8", "2", "1"), class = "factor"), wandering.easy = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("6", "4", "3", "8", "2", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    wandering.hard = structure(c(NA, 7L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("8", 
    "3", "5", "9", "2", "7", "4", "6"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am having a hard time identifying what the issue is. I have tried finding information on the error message that occurs at the last line of the code (relevant to the data frame), but I have not been able to find any information. If you have any ideas or solutions I would really appreciate hearing them!

Comment: What line causes the error? Are you sure you are spelling your column names correctly? R is case sensitive. If you need more help, please share a few rows of sample data, e.g., `dput(data[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows.

Comment: It is the line of data that starts with, "bf". I have added some sample data, thank you!

Comment: The data you've provided does not have an "rt" column. Therefore the column is undefined, producing your error.